# TensorFlow DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, terminal, conda

Trying to run python in terminal, already done:

```
 (base) C:\Users\Yinqi\trRosetta2\trRosetta>conda create -n tf tensorflow
```

But ran into this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Full traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yinqi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Python version 3.7.7, windows version 20h2

I was looking at this but not sure how to fix it: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38916

**Edit:**
It seems that running tensorflow requires cpu that supports AVX which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU's with no AVX support are no longer supported by the default tensorflow package. But there is a workaround either you have to compile from source or use  google colaboratory to work. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#download_the_tensorflow_source_code).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!